# How do I install tkinter for the default Python 2.7 on CentOS 7

Tags: python, tkinter, centos

I have installed `tkinter` package but the default Python (which is version 2.7) on CentOS 7 still complains that this package doesn't exist.

```
sudo rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-5.1804.el7.centos.2.x86_64

sudo yum install tkinter
...
Package tkinter-2.7.5-69.el7_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version

python -m tkinter
/usr/bin/python: No module named tkinter

python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 13 2018, 13:06:57) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Comment: try `python-tkinter` or `python27-tkinter` with yum

Comment: No package python-tkinter available.
No package python27-tkinter available.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Did not see it was for 2.7, you should check IUS community repo as they have python27-tkinter package

Comment: What are the instructions for enabling the IUS repo on Ubuntu 18? The IUS website has instructions only for RHEL and CentOS.

Comment: Since you asked for Centos 7 I gave you IUS repo. IUS repo provides RPM so it won't work for Ubuntu (I guess)
Check on Ubuntu if you do have **python-tkinter** or **python27-tkinter** running `apt search tkinter` or `apt search python27-tkinter`
Or by checking in you package manager.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to use a capital 'T' in Tkinter in python2.7 (changed for python3).

```
python -m Tkinter

>>> import Tkinter
```